# Msg 15064, 15275, and 15235 when running sp_spaceused

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a database on SQL Server 2000 (no, I can't upgrade right now) where I'm trying to run `sp_spaceused` on each table.

I'm getting the messages below. Any given table may have any, all, or none of the messages.

```
Server: Msg 15064, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_spaceused, Line 96
PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE KEY constraints do not have space allocated.

Server: Msg 15275, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_spaceused, Line 101
FOREIGN KEY constraints do not have space allocated.

Server: Msg 15235, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_spaceused, Line 91
Views do not have space allocated.
```

I've Google'd and Bing'd high and low, but have not found any info of use.

FWIW, I can run `sp_spaceused` without these messages against tables in another database on the same server.

Has any one else ever seen this?

### UPDATE

I did run `DBCC CHECKDB` and it did not find any problems.

The table sizes are returned by `sp_spaceused` even when the messages appear.

After reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224774(v=sql.80).aspx, I'm inclined to believe these are just notification messages, not *error* messages.

I was concerned because I had never seen these particular messages before and I've had some other problems with this database recently. Everything seems to be working ok, so I will just keep an eye on it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `sp_spaceused` against a an empty view in SQL Server 2000 results in the exact message you're seeing.

However, I just tested it in SQL Server 2019, and the issue appears to have been fixed such that `sp_spaceused` simply returns a row showing NULL values or `0 KB` depending on the column.

First, we'll create an empty table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empty_table]
(
    [empty_table_id]    int         not null
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
);
GO
```

Then create a view on the table:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[empty_table_view]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT et.[empty_table_id]
FROM [dbo].[empty_table] et
GO
```

Now, when we run `sp_spaceused` on the table, we see:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.empty_table';
```

| name | rows | reserved | data | index_size | unused |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| empty_table | 0 | 0 KB | 0 KB | 0 KB | 0 KB |

Running `sp_spaceused` on the view triggers the message you're seeing:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.empty_table_view';
```

> Msg 15235, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_spaceused, Line 91 [Batch Start Line 16]
> Views do not have space allocated.

However, if we create a unique clustered index on the view, thereby materializing it, we see:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [empty_table_view_cx] 
ON [dbo].[empty_table_view]([empty_table_id]);
```

| name | rows | reserved | data | index_size | unused |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| empty_table_view | 0 | 0 KB | 0 KB | 0 KB | 0 KB |

In SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 4 and above, the message is no longer displayed by `sp_spaceused`; SQL Server simply returns the rows displayed above showing 0 rows and 0 KB consumed.

Surprisingly, Microsoft has an old document from SQL Server 2000 still hanging around on learn.microsoft.com which [references the conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224774(v=sql.80).aspx) where you might see the message.

Comment: Imagine my surprise to get an answer 10 years later. :) Thanks!

Comment: lol, I thought you might be surprised!   And just in time, too, no doubt hahah